# Clap subcommand requires fromstr

Tags: rust, clap

I'm trying to add subcommands to my CLI tool in rust, using the clap library. When I copy the subcommand example from the [docs](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/trait.Subcommand.html)

```rust
#[derive(clap::Parser)]
struct Args {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    action: Action,
}

#[derive(clap::Subcommand)]
enum Action {
    Add,
    Remove,
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Action: FromStr` is not satisfied
|     action: Action,
|     ^^^^^^ the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `Action`
```

Is the example from the docs broken?

Comment: What version are you running? And which feature flags did you enable? Because on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fb51fc0a87c91e0864927140bba419be) and for me locally it works.

Comment: I'm running `4.0.26` with no feature flags enabled

Comment: That's unlikely, deriving needs the `derive` feature.

Comment: Oops yeah it seems I was on version 3 with derive enabled, changing versions fixed it